# How do I temporarily shut down or turn off a firebase web app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

As the question says , i don't want to delete the app , i just want to turn off so that bandwidth isn't wasted (it is just a ReactJS testing app) , is there any way I can turn it off like in Heroku where i can put the app to maintenance and it automatically revokes access to the app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Firebase CLI documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#hosting-commands), you can use the `hosting:disable` command:

```
firebase hosting:disable
```

Comment: For future me: this is **temporary**, and pushing a new version re-enables the site :) It's not as scary as the CLI warning says: `Are you sure you want to disable Firebase Hosting for the site your-site This will immediately make your site inaccessible!`