# undeploying a firebase app WITHOUT deleting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have deployed my firebase app a few days ago and I would like to shut it down. However I don't want to delete it. Is is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I temporarily shut down or turn off a firebase web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578273/how-do-i-temporarily-shut-down-or-turn-off-a-firebase-web-app)

Comment: This may be a duplicate question but what to you mean by *shut it down*? Shut what down specifically and for what purpose?